# autofac wcf client configuration

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac, wcf-client

I've created an MVC app that will call methods on a WCF service.  I've configured the client app to use autofac, autofac.integration.mvc and autofac.integration.wcf.  I have it working with the following autofac registration code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
  .Register(c => new ChannelFactory<IUserService>())
  .SingleInstance();

builder
  .Register(c => new ChannelFactory<IUserService>(
    new BasicHttpBinding(),
    new EndpointAddress(@"http://localhost:36763/UserService.svc")))
  .SingleInstance();

builder
  .Register(c => c.Resolve<ChannelFactory<IUserService>>().CreateChannel())
  .As<IUserService>()
  .UseWcfSafeRelease();
```

But I would like to be able to avoid hard coding the EndPoint address.  Is there a way to do this with without hardcoding the Endpoint address?

Update.  I tried the code listed below which works without hardcoding the endpoint address.  But it introduces a dependency on UserServiceClient.

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        string endpointAddress;
        using (var userServiceClientProxy = new UserServiceClient())
        {
            endpointAddress = userServiceClientProxy.Endpoint.Address.Uri.OriginalString;
        }

        builder
            .Register(c => new ChannelFactory<IUserService>(
                new BasicHttpBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress)))
            .SingleInstance();

        builder
            .Register(c => c.Resolve<ChannelFactory<IUserService>>().CreateChannel())
            .As<IUserService>()
            .UseWcfSafeRelease();

        builder.Register(l => LogManager.GetLogger(nameof(WcfClient2))).As<ILog>()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HomeController)));

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Comment: Have you considered putting into a config file somewhere? app.config, or a json file. You do not mention the version of MVC you are using, so I can't say which would be appropriate.

Comment: I'm using MVC 5, .NET 4.5.2.  I suppose I could get the value from the web.config for the client but I was hoping there'd be a more elegant way to determine the endpoint address.

Comment: I have heard there is a way to make an endpoint discoverable, but I have not tried it. Something  to look into.

Answer (score 0):

This is what configuration files (and as a bonus, configuration transforms) were made for! Most CI servers and deployment platforms even have mechanisms for rewriting configuration values to shield your dev environment from production. It's just good practice and there's not a better way, especially considering someone besides you may eventually work on this thing you are building, and they'll want to see something familiar in place!